# how to insert image in database and store it in folder and display it back

Tags: php, html, database

I'm creating one PHP blog, I don't know how to code to insert an image and store it in both database table and my assets/image folder and retrieve it back to my webpage, this my my code anyone help me.

1. I Want to store image in my Database table
2. Also that image need to save in my (assets/images) folder.
3. And finally that image have to display it on My Webpage

```html
<div class="content">
 
    <h1>Add New Product</h1>

    <?php

    //if form has been submitted process it
    if(isset($_POST['submit'])){

 

        //collect form data
        extract($_POST);

        //very basic validations
        if($ProductTitle ==''){
            $error[] = 'Please enter the Product Title.';
        }

        if($Price ==''){
            $error[] = 'Please enter the Price.';
        }

        if($ProductContent ==''){
            $error[] = 'Please enter the Product Description.';
        }

        if(!isset($error)){

          try {



    //insert into database
$Slug = slug($ProductTitle);

    //insert into database
   $stmt = $db->prepare('INSERT INTO techno_blog (ProductTitle,Slug,Price,ProductContent,articleDate) VALUES (:ProductTitle, :Slug, :Price, :ProductContent, :articleDate)') ;

$stmt->execute(array(
    ':ProductTitle' => $ProductTitle,
    ':Slug' => $Slug,//Blog article slug 
    ':Price' => $Price,
    ':ProductContent' => $ProductContent,
    ':articleDate' => date('Y-m-d H:i:s')
  
));


//add categories
 $ProductId = $db->lastInsertId();
if(is_array($categoryId)){
    foreach($_POST['categoryId'] as $categoryId){
        $stmt = $db->prepare('INSERT INTO techno_cat_links (ProductId,categoryId)VALUES(:ProductId,:categoryId)');
        $stmt->execute(array(
            ':ProductId' => $ProductId,
            ':categoryId' => $categoryId
        ));
    }
}


    //redirect to index page
    header('Location: index.php?action=added');
    exit;

}catch(PDOException $e) {
                echo $e->getMessage();
            }

        }

    }

    //check for any errors
    if(isset($error)){
        foreach($error as $error){
            echo '<p class="message">'.$error.'</p>';
        }
    }
    ?>
 <form action="" method="post">

        <h2><label>Product Title</label><br>
        <input type="text" name="ProductTitle" style="width:100%;" value="<?php if(isset($error)){ echo $_POST['ProductTitle'];}?>"></h2>

        <h2><label>Price</label>
        <input type="text" name="Price"><?php if(isset($error)){ echo $_POST['Price'];}?></input>
        <h2>
        <h2><label>Product Description</label><br>
        <textarea name="ProductContent" id="textarea1" class="mceEditor" cols="120" rows='20'><?php if(isset($error)){ echo $_POST['ProductContent'];}?></textarea></h2>
        
 <fieldset>
    <h2><legend>Categories</legend>

    <?php    
$checked = null;
    $stmt2 = $db->query('SELECT categoryId, categoryName FROM techno_category ORDER BY categoryName');

    while($row2 = $stmt2->fetch()){

        if(isset($_POST['categoryId'])){

            if(in_array($row2['categoryId'], $_POST['categoryId'])){
               $checked="checked='checked'";
            }else{
               

            }
        }

 echo "<input type='checkbox' name='categoryId[]' value='".$row2['categoryId']."' $checked> ".$row2['categoryName']."<br />";
    }

    ?>
</h2>
</fieldset>
       
        <button name="submit" class="subbtn">Submit</button>


    </form>


</div>
```

```html
<?php
                try {   
                    //selecting data by id 
                    $stmt = $db->query('SELECT ProductId, ProductTitle, Slug, Price, articleDate FROM techno_blog ORDER BY ProductId DESC');  
                    while($row = $stmt->fetch()){
                    
                    echo '
                    <div>
                    
                    //Need to display my image here
                    
                    <h1><a href="'.$row['Slug'].'">'.$row['ProductTitle'].'</a></h1>                             
                    <hr>
                    <p>Released on '.date('jS M Y', strtotime($row['articleDate'])).' in 
                    ';
                    >
```

Comment: Uploading an image and saving it, you can find on google. The way to save it, is just insert a string that contains the path to your `assets/images/img.jpg`. Then retrieve that with your query and just put that in the `<img src="your-img-path"/>`

Comment: can u pls tell the detailed code, I've tried every thing but cannot get the correct code.

Comment: You cant have tried everything, otherwise you'd have found the solution

Comment: I just tried what i know that's it....any answer plss

Comment: https://www.studentstutorial.com/php/php-retrieve-image & https://www.studentstutorial.com/php/php-insert-image ? (search terms were tutorial+image+php+database)